# how to extract portion text between "if then else" keywords from a docx file in python

Tags: python, text, extract, docx

I need to extract the specific portion of text (IF bla bla THEN bla bla ELSE bla bla) from a docx file.

I'm working with python-docx but I have some problems.

I'm able to print the lines starting with IF but I'm not able to extract the rest of string of interest.

example: in the docx file there is:

> bla bla text bla bla if this signal1 is on then do something else do other and other. bla bla text bla if signal2 is off then do nothing else shot the sheriff. bla bla bla

I would to extract:

1. > if this signal1 is on then do something else do other and other.
2. > if signal2 is off then do nothing else shot the sheriff

I'm working in this way:

```
import readDocx

def main():

text = readDocx.getText('prova.docx')

for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("IF"):
        print (line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where `readDocx` is the other python file like this:

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
   doc = docx.Document(filename)
   fullText = []
   for para in doc.paragraphs:
       fullText.append(para.text)
   return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import readDocx,re
#omitting lines...

pattern = re.compile(r"if (.+)\.")

for line in text.splitlines():
    if pattern.search(line):
        print(pattern.search()[0])
```